# can't get past block if

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format cells with interior color based on value of cell

tried adding end if and changing end if with Else. Just cant get past issue. either a block if issue or Else without if issue.

```
Sub Colorcell()
    For Each cel In Range(a2, a5)
    If cel.Value = "Red" Then
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    ElseIf cel.Value = "blue" Then
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
```

receive

> Compile error Else without If.

Expect to color the cell with indicated color in code when matches color verbiage

Comment: You need to end your `With` blocks: `End With`

Comment: Please post your entire sub. You've included the beginning, but not the end, so we can't tell what's missing at the end.

Comment: `Range(a2, a5)`. is not a valid reference: `Range("A2:A5")` perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the `With` and `If` statements:

```
Sub Colorcell()
    ' I assume the range below is what you mean by `Range(a2,a5)`...
    For Each cel In Range("A2:A5")
    If cel.Value = "Red" Then
        With cel.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5296274
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    ElseIf cel.Value = "blue" Then
        With cel.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12611584
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Also a thought - why not just use conditional formatting instead of a macro?

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
Sub Colorcell()
    For Each cel In Range("A2:A5")
        If cel.Value = "Red" Then
            cel.Interior.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf cel.Value = "blue" Then
            cel.Interior.Color = vbBlue
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Note, this is case sensitive.